# how to read this matlab for loop with % operator

Tags: matlab, for-loop

here is a portion of matlab code I'm to translate in another language

```
for a=10%[7 10 12],%20 50 200]
    for b=20% 25 30],%50],
        for c=1 %1.25 1.5],% 2]
```

I'm not really a matlab user, and dont understand these lines.
I imagine the right sides of assignments define lists of values to iterate on,
but don't understand the meaning of the % and the [], 
and why are there more ']' than '[' and why there is a ',' at the end of second line?

Comment: `%` is for comment, after that is nothing. So those loops of yours have just `one` value each, means no loop. It seems the code has problems

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot these % comment, and spent some time trying to find a meaning to this :)

Comment: But the code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It does now, i understood different ranges were used and commented, and the loop was reduced by commenting to single values of each parameter researched (it was an optimisation loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB `for` loops are like this

```
for i = [0 1 5 2]
    statements
end
```

or

```
for i = 1 : 1 : 10  % i iterates over integers from `1` to `10`
    statement
end
```

And the `%` is used for comments,

```
% MATLAB comment line
```

So simplified form of your code is:

```
for a = 10
  for b = 20
    for c = 1
```

which is like

```
 a = 10
 b = 20
 c = 1
```